# Grouping, sorting and picking one record with combine field value in Java

Tags: java, sorting, grouping

I am trying to group, sort and pick top object from the group which will also have list of fields values from all the objects of the group for one field. For example give records

| CustId | Time | Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 06:00:00 | 100 |
| 1 | 06:05:00 | 101 |
| 1 | 06:10:00 | 102 |
| 2 | 06:00:00 | 101 |
| 2 | 06:10:00 | 103 |
| 3 | 06:15:00 | 102 |
| 3 | 06:10:00 | 103 |

Result

| CustId | Time | Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 06:10:00 | 100#101#102 |
| 2 | 06:10:00 | 101#103 |
| 3 | 06:15:00 | 102#103 |

`Product` field is an `String` type so hoping I can join strings to form that desire format. Order of product does not matter.

I have two block of codes. First to group, sort and pick first one. Second to generate product list. However I am unable to combine and update `Product` column with list.

First Part

```java
Map<String, CustEvent> map = custEventList.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        CustEvent::getCustId,
                        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                                Collectors.toList(),
                                values -> values.stream()
                                        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(CustEvent::getTime, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())).reversed())
                                        .collect(toList()).get(0)
                        )));
```

Second part

```java
Map<String, String> custProducts = custEventList.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(CustEvent::getCustId,
                        mapping(CustEvent::getProduct, joining("#"))));
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the product list generation code(second snippet part) right after finding the `maxTimeEvent` (`CustEvent` with the maximum time for each group). Post that, you can create a string(say `products`) by streaming through the `values`, mapping each `CustEvent` to its `Product` field, and then joining them using the `Collectors.joining("#")` collector. Finally, set the string as the `Product` field for the `maxTimeEvent`, and return the `maxTimeEvent` as result. Something like:

```java
Map<String, CustEvent> map = custEventList.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
        CustEvent::getCustId,
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.toList(),
            values -> {
                CustEvent maxTimeEvent = values.stream()
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(CustEvent::getTime, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())).reversed())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);

                String products = values.stream()
                    .map(CustEvent::getProduct)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining("#"));

                maxTimeEvent.setProduct(products);
                return maxTimeEvent;
            }
)));
```

*[demo here](https://onlinegdb.com/KrKx850Dl)*

Comment: I am getting `Incompatible paramter types in lambda expression: expected List<Object> but found List<CustEvent>` error on `values`

Comment: @αƞjiβ based on the code you provided in your question, it doesn't seem there is some issue with the type inference of lambda but as a workaround try explicitly defining the types in lambda expression. Here is a sample code: https://onlinegdb.com/6EI_9Dmf2

Comment: I am surprise too. My sample extract code does not have this issue. However real implementation in project has.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `CustEvent` is:

```
record CustEvent(String id, LocalTime time, String product) {}
```

These are the things you need to do (the collector to use is in parentheses)

1. group by `id` (`groupingBy`)
2. for each group, do two things (`teeing`):

   1. find the `CustEvent` with the max `time` in that group (`maxBy`)
   2. join the `product`s of the events in that group with "#" (`mapping` + `joining`)
3. combine the results of the above two operation into a new `CustEvent` (the third parameter of `teeing`)

```
Map<String, CustEvent> result = events.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
        CustEvent::id,
        Collectors.teeing(
            Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(CustEvent::time)),
            Collectors.mapping(
                CustEvent::product,
                Collectors.joining("#")
            ),
            (maxCust, products) -> maxCust.map( // maxCust is an Optional<CustEvent>
                x -> new CustEvent(x.id(), x.time(), products)
            ).get() // this is safe because groupingBy ensures at least one item in each group
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: I am still on Java11

Comment: @αƞjiβ oh! `teeing` isn’t available yet. Never mind then.